# Setting images of a button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have come across an issue I cannot resolve.

I have a `struct` and would like to change the image of a button in each collection view. My text/image works as according to plan. However, when trying to change the image button I am struggling. Could someone please help me?

```
class CollectionViewContent{

    var caption = ""
    var mainImage: UIImage!
    var userProfileImage : UIButton


    init(caption: String, mainImage: UIImage!, userProfileImage : UIButton! )
    {
        self.description = description
        self.mainImage = featuredImage
        self.userProfileImage = postedUserProfileImage
    }


    static func  showPosts() -> [Posts]
    {
        return [
            Posts(description: "Sweet", mainImage: UIImage(named: "Image 1"), postedUserProfileImage:!),
                   Posts(description: "Awesome", mainImage: UIImage(named: "Image 2")!),
                   Posts(description: "WOW!", mainImage: UIImage(named: "Image 3")!

                  )
        ]
    }


}
```

This is my collectionViewCell class

```
class colViewContetCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    var posts: Posts! {
        didSet {
            updateUI()

        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var featuredImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postCaptionLabel: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var postedUserProfileImage: UIButton!



    func updateUI() {
        postCaptionLabel?.text! = posts.title
        featuredImage?.image! = posts.featuredImage
        postedUserProfileImage = posts.postedUserProfileImage
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

}
```

I think this line of code is incorrect by the way, I am not too sure.

```
 postedUserProfileImage = posts.postedUserProfileImage
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
postedUserProfileImage = posts.postedUserProfileImage
```

You should do:

```
postedUserProfileImage.setImage(posts.postedUserProfileImage.image(for: UIControlState.normal), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Since `postedUserProfileImage` is a `UIButton`, you need to use the `setImage` method to set it's image for a control specific control state. If no images are set for the other control states, the image for the normal state is used for the others too.

And since `posts.postedUserProfileImage` is also a `UIButton` (as mentioned in the comments below) you need to get the button's image via the `image(for:)` method.

Comment: OK, I see. How would I be able to set the image? Thank you for the swift reply :)

Comment: See my code above :) That tells you how to set the image. Unless you mean something else when you say "set the image"?

Comment: I see, I have added the line of code and I have an error "Cannot convert value of type 'UIButton' to expected argument type 'UImage?'". I basically wish to have one button, but in each collection view the image of the button is changed to whichever image I select. :)

Comment: Ah, since the code you posted did not specify what the type for `posts.postedUserProfileImage` I thought it was a UIImage. If it is a button and you are simply trying to set the image for one button to another, then see my modified code above.